# Proving that a union of a countable and an uncountable set is equivalent to the uncountable set (proof check)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> Let $A$, $B$ be sets with $|B|=\aleph _0$ and $|A|>\aleph _0$, Prove that $|A\cup B| = |A|$

I've already seen somewhere here (though can't seem to find it now) a proof using the fact that $\aleph _0 + \kappa = \kappa$ in that case, but we haven't learned it yet so I wanted to prove without arithmetics on cardinality, is my proof ok?

Since $\left|A\right|>\aleph_{0}$
  we know that we can find a one-to-one function $f:\mathbb{N}\to A$ , and notice that $f:\mathbb{N}\to f\left(\mathbb{N}\right)$ is bijective and therefore we can find it's inverse $f^{-1}$.

Similarly since $B$ is countable we can find a bijection $g:\mathbb{N}\to B$, which also has an inverse $g^{-1}$. Now using these two functions we can define a bijection $t:\mathbb{N}\to f\left(\mathbb{N}\right)\mathbb{\cup}B$
  by $$t(n)=\begin{cases}
f\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right) & n\mbox{ is odd}\\
g\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) & n\mbox{ is even}
\end{cases}$$

Therefore we will define our function $F:A\to A\cup B$ as follow: $$F\left(a\right)=\begin{cases}
t(f^{-1}(a)) & a\in f\left(\mathbb{N}\right)\\
a & a\notin f\left(\mathbb{N}\right)
\end{cases}$$

First the function is indeed well defined, since $f^{-1}$ is an inverse for each $a\in f\left(\mathbb{N}\right)$ we will get $f^{-1}\left(a\right)=n$, and then $t\left(n\right)\in f\left(\mathbb{N}\right)\cup B\subseteq A\cup B$.

It's also one to one as given $F\left(a\right)=F\left(b\right)$ we know that either $F\left(a\right)$,$F\left(b\right)\notin f\left(\mathbb{N}\right)$ and then $a=b$ or $F\left(a\right),F\left(b\right)\in f\left(\mathbb{N}\right)$ and since $f^{-1}$ is a bijection and $t$ is a bijection 
$$t\left(f^{-1}(a)\right)=t\left(f^{-1}(b)\right)\iff f^{-1}\left(a\right)=f^{-1}\left(b\right)\iff a=b$$

To see it's onto, given $a\in A\cup B$
 , if $a\in A\setminus f\left(\mathbb{N}\right)$
  then $f\left(a\right)=a$
 , otherwise if $a\in f\left(\mathbb{N}\right)$
 , then $f^{-1}\left(a\right)=n$
 , but then we can find $f\left(2n+1\right)=b\in A$
  and we get that $$F\left(b\right)=t\left(2n+1\right)=f\left(\frac{2n+1-1}{2}\right)=a$$
 Finally if $a\in B$ we can find $g^{-1}\left(a\right)=n$ and find $f\left(2n\right)=b\in A$, and then $$F\left(b\right)=t\left(2n\right)=g\left(\frac{2n}{2}\right)=a$$ Therefore we have found a bijection $F:A\to A\cup B$
  and $A\sim A\cup B$
 .

Comment: Your proof looks fine.

Comment: If you know the Cantor-Bernstein theorem, you can realize that you don't need to prove $F$ is surjective.

Comment: @tetori This is the next topic so I guess I'll realize it soon :P